# WP CLI in WP 5.3 with PHP 7.4

Tags: rest-api, json, wp-cli

Working with the `WP REST API` `WP-CLI` in WP 5.4, by selecting PHP 7.3 the call to `wp post` works as usually:

```
wp post list
```

But changing to PHP 7.4 (current) throws me the following errors:

```
Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 707
Deprecated: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/DocParser.php on line 75
Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 656
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2245
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Parser.php on line 278
```

Selecting PHP 7.3 again solves the problem.

Following [this WP note](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/11/wordpress-and-php-7-4/) as cited, WP 5.3 would supposedly cover these problems, but WP 5.4 still throws notices.

> Using the curly brace syntax will now trigger a deprecated notice in
>   PHP 7.4 with the plan to remove the feature entirely in PHP 8.0 (or
>   another future release).

Is this a bug? Should I always use the last PHP version? Or as it seems, keep some steps before the last update?

Comment: what's the wp-cli version?

Comment: I got lost on that. I dont remember me installing `WP-CLI` at all. The installed version from `wp cli info` is `WP-CLI version: 2.3.0`. Current version seems to be `2.4.0` [ref.](https://wp-cli.org/). I would'n break anything if I update?

Comment: @Brethlosze I would update. I updated from 2.0.0 to 2.4.0 and my PHP 7.4 notices went away. `wp cli update`